# textmate bundles not recognizing differences

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

So i'm trying to make a set of grammars recognizing different file extensions properly.

All my files (js/css/html) end with template. This is similiar to how ruby does it with js.erb, css.erb, etc. So I modified the file type attribute to js.template css.template and template itself for html. But it doesn't seem to work. They just default to template even though there are more specific ones.

But for some reason Textmate doesn't want to recognize my different file extensions. Any idea why this would be happening or why the Ruby grammars seem to work but mine don't?

Answer (score 0):

The detailed answer depends on the scope and therefore syntax highlighting you want. The general approach is as follows:

1. Open the Bundles Editor (Control-Meta-Command-B)
2. Search for the language definition of JavaScript, i.e. in the JavaScript bundle is a grammar definition called "JavaScript"
3. Open it and look for the line which starts with "filetypes", which should look like `fileTypes = ( 'js', 'htc', 'jsx' );`
4. Add your own file ending, i.e. "js.template"
5. Close the Bundle Editor or activate another snippet / command / grammar or click the Test button to reload the grammar (note that manual language definitions are preferred over file ending, so create a new file with that extension and load it with TextMate to make sure it works)
6. Repeat for any grammar definition you want to work with another file ending, i.e. HTML and CSS

This way you will have the default syntax highlighting working in your files with .template endings. However, the Ruby on Rails bundle extends those grammars a little, so maybe you want to extend the supported filetypes of these grammars as well.